# Mesh wifi nodes cabling options

Tags: cable, wifi-configuration

I have a main asus router with 3 asus lyra mini mesh satellites. For reliability I am going to cable the satellites to the main router (I cannot place them in way to get good reception from one satellite to the next).

I have two options for the cabling, first is each satellite directly into its own port on the router. The second is to chain the satellites with the cable running from one port on the router to mini 1, then a cable from the mini 1 to mini 2, and then a cable from mini 2 to mini 3.

In terms of cabling work, the second chaining option is much easier for me to do.  Does this configuration have a significant impact on overall performance? The broadband speed at my property is only about 45Mbps but the kids will be connected to mini 3, streaming goodness knows what, so will performance/bandwidth be capable of handling this?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link in this daisy chain will be carrying data of all the other nodes, so we have to confirm that it can handle it.

ASUS Lyra Mini Mesh satellites have 1 Gbps Ethernet ports, that's more than enough. We don't know what's the speed of router's port, but even if it would downgrade the connection to 100 Mbps, that should still be sufficient.

Daisy chaining may increase the latency (aka. "ping") slightly, but it should still be negligible compared to latency introduced by wireless.